# Foundation's Card Component with <p> instead of <h4>?

Tags: html, zurb-foundation, accessibility

I'm reading through the docs of Foundation's Card component and I see that they are using `<h4>` tags in the cards. For my purpose, I don't need to have my text as a heading and I don't have `<h3>` on my page so I don't want to be skipping heading levels.

So I'm wondering if it would be good practice from an accessibility point of view to have my text in a `<p>` tag instead of what they have as `<h4>` tags in the docs?

Example from Foundation:

```
<div class="card" style="width: 300px;">
  <div class="card-divider">
    <h4>I'm featured</h4>
  </div>
  <img src="assets/img/generic/rectangle-1.jpg">
  <div class="card-section">
    <p>This card makes use of the card-divider element.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do:

```
<div class="card" style="width: 300px;">
  <div class="card-divider">
    <p>I'm featured</p>
  </div>
  <img src="assets/img/generic/rectangle-1.jpg">
  <div class="card-section">
    <p>This card makes use of the card-divider element.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an automatic accessibility problem if you skip heading levels.  There are valid cases where it makes sense but it should only happen rarely.

If you remove the heading from the cards, that will make it harder for screen reader users to find the cards.  Screen reading software has shortcut keys to make finding different types of elements on the page easier.  In this case, I can navigate to all the headings by using the <kbd>H</kbd> key (or on iOS, with VoiceOver, I can set my rotor to "headings" and swipe down to move to the next heading).

I would recommend keeping the headings, even if they skip levels.  It's a worse problem **not** having headings than it is to skip levels.

However, if you have control over generating a <p> instead of an <h4>, do you not have control of changing the <h4> to an <h3>?